# for loop based on dynamic list python

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

**Edit:**
The desired behaviour of the program is to find the number sequences that have an increasing trend, so I want to generate from `ks` list a list like this:
`desiredList=[[97,122],[98,111],[98,101,103,103,104]]`

I have the following, my goal is to run the for loop based on the length of the list, the list length gets changed inside the for loop itself. Python takes into account only the length before the for loop, when the length of the list is changed in the loop it still takes the older value before the loop. Here is the code:

```
ks=[97,122,111,98,111,98,101,103,103,104,97]
splitLine=2
counter=[]
for i in range(0,len(ks)):
   a=ks[i:splitLine]
   while len(a)>1:
        for j in range(0,len(a)):
            m=j
            n=j+1
            if(a[m]-a[n]<=0):
                c=c+1
                k=splitLine+c-1
                a.append(ks[k]) #When append happens, the for loop still takes the older value of len(a) instead of new value
            else:
                a.pop(-1)
                counter.append(a)
                splitLine=splitLine+1
                a=[]
                break
```

Comment: You explained the behavior of your `for` loop. But the problem statement you are trying to solve is unclear. Please edit the question to explain the desired behavior. Also mention the sample input and the desired output

Comment: Several problems in your code apart from the one you state. `a[m]` and `a[n]` are strings, and where do you first define `c`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Modifying a list while you iterate is nearly always a bad idea

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is probably nesting too many loops for the problem it is trying to solve.

**This first implementation contains an error.** See below for the fix.

Try something along these lines perhaps:

```
l = [97,122,111,98,111,98,101,103,103,104,97]
out = []
acc = []
for v in l:
    if len(acc)==0 or v >= acc[-1]:
        acc.append(v)
    else:
        if len(acc) > 1:
            out.append(acc)
        acc = [v]

print(out)
>>>[[97, 122], [98, 111], [98, 101, 103, 103, 104]]
```

**That previous code is slow and can drop the last found fragment**. I found that error while running random tests on it to try an optimized version. The following code shows the original code with the correction and the optimized version which can be 30% faster.

```
def original(l):
    out = []
    acc = []
    added = False
    for v in l:
        if len(acc)==0 or v >= acc[-1]:
            acc.append(v)
        else:
            added = False
            acc = [v]

        if acc is not None and len(acc)>1 and not added:
            added = True
            out.append(acc)
    return out


def optimized(l):
    out = []

    acc = None
    tmp = None
    deb_v = False
    for v in l:
        prev =  acc[-1] if (acc is not None and len(acc)) else tmp
        if prev is not None and v >= prev:
            if tmp is not None:
                acc = []
                acc.append(tmp)
                out.append(acc)
                tmp = None
            acc.append(v)
        else:
            acc = None
            tmp = v
    return out


# The original test data
l = [97,122,111,98,111,98,101,103,103,104,97]
assert original(l) == optimized(l) == [[97,122],[98,111],[98,101,103,103,104]]

# A list that triggered last-fragment-dropped error
l = [57, 16, 6, 19, 40, 3, 4, 13, 2, 70, 85, 65, 32, 69, 54, 51, 95, 74, 92, 46, 45, 26, 0, 61, 99, 43, 67, 71, 97, 10, 18, 73, 88, 47, 33, 82, 25, 75, 93, 80, 23, 37, 87, 90, 49, 15, 35, 63, 17, 64, 5, 72, 89, 21, 50, 8, 41, 86, 31, 78, 52, 76, 56, 42, 77, 36, 11, 60, 39, 22, 68, 27, 24, 28, 59, 96, 29, 38, 12, 79, 53, 9, 83, 94, 34, 14, 7, 48, 30, 20, 66, 62, 91, 58, 81, 1, 98, 44, 55, 84]
assert original(l) == optimized(l)

# Random testing
import random
l = list(range(100))
random.shuffle(l)
assert original(l) == optimized(l)

# Timing!
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("original(l)", globals={"l":l, "original": original}))
# 43.95869998800117

print(timeit.timeit("optimized(l)", globals={"l":l, "optimized": optimized}))
# 34.82134292599949
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix for your looping problem would be to swap out your `for` loop for a `while` loop.  Change this:

```
for j in range(0,len(a)):
    # <loop contents>
```

to this:

```
j = 0
while j < len(a):
    # <loop contents>
    j += 1
```

The `for` loop is grabbing values of `j` out of a `range` (a `list` in Python 2, and a generator object in Python 3).  This `range` is calculated when the `for` loop is run the first time; it will not update after that, no matter what you do to `a`.

The `while` loop gives you more control in this situation, because you can specify the condition under which you want to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Moinuddin says, the root of your problem isn't clear to us. However, the code  below shows how you can keep iterating over a list as its length changes:

```
def iterate_for_static_list_length(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        yield i
        l.append(object())


def iterate_for_dynamic_list_length(l):
    for i, _ in enumerate(l):
        yield i
        l.append(object())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [object()] * 3

    print('Static implementation')
    for value in iterate_for_static_list_length(l):
        input(value)

    print('\nDynamic implementation')
    for value in iterate_for_dynamic_list_length(l):
        input(value)
```

**Output**

```
Static implementation
0
1
2

Dynamic implementation
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

This program will keep going forever. In your code I can see that you *conditionally* append to the list within the loop, so it seems like it should terminate eventually.